# How to get better rigging view

Tags: modeling, rigging, wireframe

I was practicing rigging. So I picked up a model from internet and started rigging but I can't see the armature through hand.

[image: blender rigging view problem]

After enabling X-ray armature can be seen, but only in object mode, when I went to edit mode it was like as it was. Then I turned of wire-frame but that wasn't that much helpful.

After changing object mode:

[image: After changing object mode]

After changing edit mode:

[image: After changing edit mode]

I have tried wire-frame too. What should I do ?

Disabled wire-frame for hand, disabled x-ray for armature.

[image: err]

Comment: Did you try reverting the theme to the default? Did you try setting the bone display to x-ray in the display tab in the bone properties pane?.

Comment: I have tried all those , but no luck

Comment: Can you provide a link to your blend file?

Comment: Of course ... Blend file is here ... https://github.com/maifeeulasad/Blender-Projects/blob/master/hand.blend

Comment: Try disabling x-ray on the hand object in the object display panel.

Comment: Not helpful at all..  Have you seen the file ?

Comment: yes and it works fine. I disabled x-ray on the hand and activated it on the bones. Everything is visible in edit and pose modes. I tried wireframe and solid view both work

Comment: check the images https://imgur.com/a/Osg0mJB

Comment: I also disabled wireframe drawing on the hand geo in the display properties

Comment: I have added a snap, doesn't work..

Comment: Try these steps in order. 
-Open blender and reset to factory settings,
-Open your hand.blend file without loading the layout (look at the options in the bottom left)
- Select the hand geometry and disable X-ray and wire on its display options.
- Select the bones and enable x-ray in the display panel.
- Switch your viewport mode to solid, or shaded and bones should appear on top of the hand geometry clearly.
-If it doesn't work then you have some other issue. as I got the file to work normally and you can see the results in my previous comment

Comment: Can you send me a drive link of yours ?? That would be very helpful , if you want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94518/discussion-between-samir-rahamtalla-and-maifee-ul-asad).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the hand also has X-ray mode on, so the two are interfering. Go into the object menu of the hand, click display, and then uncheck X-ray.

Comment: I have added a snap, doesn't work..

Comment: It worked for me when I opened your blender file.

Comment: Make sure the armature has x-ray ON, and the hand model has x-ray OFF.